# Can't import the named export 'cloneElement' from non EcmaScript module

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have the same issue and i have used create-react-app
my react-toastify version is ^9.0.8. please help me
Here is the full message:
./node_modules/react-toastify/dist/react-toastify.esm.mjs
Can't import the named export 'cloneElement' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Answer (score 28):

I had the same problem, I just downgrade the version of react-toastify from 9.0.8 to 8.0.0 and then re-runned the repo and it started working

Comment: Did the same, but last 8.x version works which is currently 8.2.0.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. I tried some versions, but **version 9.0.0** is ok and it's worked.

`"react-toastify": "^9.0.0"`
run :  `npm install react-toastify@9.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

Update your `react-scripts` to last version:

```js
npm i react-scripts@latest
```